# R gdalwarp issues under new PROJ6 libraries

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, r

i have a workflow that incorporates gdalwarp from gdalUtils in R, to reproject 1km UK data in British National Grid to 0.01 degree data in WGS84. This is always a tricky transformation due to the awkwardly similar cell sizes, but i found that gdalwarp, using the cubic transformation, struck the best balance in terms of maintaining surface total and also cell values;

```
# i know that sp and CRS is deprecated here but has had little effect on projectRaster etc.
BNG <- CRS("+init=epsg:27700")  # British National Grid
LL <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # For LatLong

# BNG file being read in to transform
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1350, 980, 1323000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 1000, 1000  (x, y)
extent     : -230000, 750000, -50000, 1300000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs 
source     : C:/Path/BNG1km_file.tif
names      : my_BNG_raster 
values     : 0.0001111782, 873.1203  (min, max)

# structure of WGS84 raster being trasnformed to is in the gdalwarp function but for clarity;
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1250, 1840, 2300000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
extent     : -13.8, 4.6, 49, 61.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : NA, NA  (min, max)

# gdalwarp function
gdalwarp(paste0("C:/Path/BNG1km_file.tif"), dstfile = paste0("C:/Path/LL0.01_file.tif"), 
s_srs = BNG, t_srs = LL, r = "cubic", tr = c(0.01, 0.01), 
te=c(-13.8, 49, 4.6, 61.5), output_Raster=TRUE, overwrite=TRUE, verbose=TRUE)


Checking gdal_installation...
GDAL version 2.1.1
GDAL command being used: "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\gdalwarp.exe" -overwrite  -te -13.8 49 4.6 61.5 -tr 0.01 0.01 -s_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs" -r "cubic" -of "GTiff" "C:/Path/BNG1km_file.tif" "C:/Path/LL0.01_file.tif"
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 1250, 1840, 2300000, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
extent     : -13.8, 4.6, 49, 61.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : C:/Path/BNG1km_file.tif 
names      : layer 

# new surface
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1250, 1840, 2300000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.01, 0.01  (x, y)
extent     : -13.8, 4.6, 49, 61.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : -1621.413, 7279.047  (min, max)
```

Last year this exact function gave me a good reprojection in terms of data  totals and values, but this year it went haywire (21 times the surface total). Also when using the function against last year's data again, it also produced very poor results.

Has gdalUtils not taken into account the GDAL and PROJ6 updates? or has gdalwarp gone wrong somewhere?

edit: i can see the gdalwarp help (GDAL documentation, not R) has a -ct argument for WKT strings in the update, but this has not made it to R yet
https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html

Comment: Can you edit your Q and add in the output from that function call? Especially the command line that is being constructed and written out. And also what the shapes of your input and output TIFFs are? Maybe read them into R and `summary()` them?

Comment: The "datum" isn't deprecated but the PROJ format of the coordinate system is. The `sp` package (which is where I'm guessing your CRS function comes from) only seems to work with PROJ strings though. But without knowing what's passed to the underlying gdalwarp command line we're at a loss...

Comment: thanks, ive added some info - i think gdalUtils has not been updated yet. I might turn to `terra::resample` actually, as i have updated any vector to work to incorporate the developments but not raster work, so i think it's time.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but it's worth a shot. Instead of `BNG <- CRS("+init=epsg:27700")` try `BNG <- CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:27700")`